# CPLEX Not working on MACOS after OS Update (Big Sur)

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, cplex, macos-big-sur, ibm-ilog-opl

I am having some troubles working with CPLEX since I updated my OS to Big Sur. Before it was working just fine, now when I open the interface doesn't open correctly all the time and when it does I keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException each time I try to open a file.
If anyone had the same problem or knows how to solve this I would appreciate the help. (I tried different versions of CPLEX and it's always the same problem).

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Only the current Eclipse 2020-12 runs properly on macOS 11, earlier versions had problems.

Comment: @R88 We are updating the Eclipse in CPLEX - What edition (academic, community, full) of CPLEX are you using ? I'll notify you when the fix is available. Thanks

Comment: @Viu-LongKong I am currently using the academic edition. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @R88 The fix for BigSur is available now - Please drop an email to cos-ai-support@wwpdl.vnet.ibm.com with the email you used to register to Academic Initiative, I will send you a download link.

Comment: @Viu-LongKong I've sent you an email for the link. I need it for a university project